# Portable security role mapping with jdbc realms

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, deployment, portability

I am finalizing a Java EE 6 application. The app has been developed using GlassFish, but I want to make it portable across different application servers.

The security has been implemented by defining users and groups in the application's DataSource, and so by using GlassFish's jdbcRealm. I know that there exist similar implementations in other App Servers (although I haven't looked at the details, yet).

In order to make my app portable, I need to understand if **the mapping between Security Roles and principals / users** can be defined in the app server itself, or in the application source code, without using the app-server-specific deployment descriptor `glassfish-web.xml` or equivalent. This would avoid the deployer's task of editing the `.war` file, which is something I'd like, since the application has to be portable.

Since I have mapped the roles to application-defined groups with the same names, the code I'd like to remove is

```
  <security-role-mapping>
      <role-name>RoleGroup1</role-name>
      <group-name>RoleGroup1</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
      <role-name>RoleGroup2</role-name>
      <group-name>RoleGroup2</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
```

Comment: Glassfish provides a setting called "Default Principal To Role Mapping" which automatically generates these mappings if you keep the Groups and Roles the same. You can enable it by ticking the checkbox found under Configurations > server-config > Security. I anticipate that other Application Servers have a similar feature. Since you need to provide instructions to configure (at least) the Realm for each Application Server which you deploy to, you could tack this instruction to the end of those notes and spare yourself the need to populate a container-specific mapping file.

Answer (score -1):

As per EBJ 3.1 spec:

> **17.2.5.3 Declaration of Security Roles Referenced from the Bean’s Code**
>
> ...
>
> If the  DeclareRoles annotation is not used, the Bean Provider must
>   use the  security-role-ref elements of the deployment descriptor to
>   declare the security roles referenced in the  code. The
>   security-role-ref elements are defined as follows:
>
> - Declare the name of the security role using the role-name element. The name must be the
>     security role name that is used as a parameter to the
>     isCallerInRole(String roleName) method.
> - Optionally provide a description of the security role in the description element.

Additionally:

> If the deployment descriptor is used, the The Bean Provider and/or
>   Application Assembler uses the  security-role deployment descriptor
>   element as follows:
>
> - Define each security role using a security-role element.
> - Use the role-name element to define the name of the security role.
> - Optionally, use the description element to provide a description of a security role.
>
> The following example illustrates security roles definition in a
>   deployment descriptor.
>
> ```
> <assembly-descriptor>
>   <security-role>
>     <description>
>       This role includes the employees of the
>       enterprise who are allowed to access the 
>       employee self-service application. This role
>       is allowed only to access his/her own 
>       information.
>     </description>
>     <role-name>employee</role-name>
>   </security-role>
> ```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. The OP would like to map Roles to Principals without using a container-specific configuration file.